# Google App Script published as a web app not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have currently a simple Hello World Google App Script following [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)

[image: Google App Script]

I published it, giving access to anyone on the internet (including anonymous users) and then get both a xxx/dev and xxx/exec urls (latter for "published versions" usage, latter for work in progress usage).

[image: Publishing google app script]

None of those URL are currently working when I call it in my Browser (or through a cURL command) :

[image: Browser error]

Any idea on what could go wrong ?

Note : I already published some Google App Scripts in the past and they are still working today. It is as if my "new" google app scripts was not getting published.

Comment: you are using doGET you need to pass parameters in the URL like "?username=jsmith&age=21" , did you tried that ?

Comment: Nope, query parameters are not mandatory in google app scripts, and request object doesn't contain "only" query parameters. Was related to a bad generated URL when using multiple accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be because you are logged into multiple Google accounts. Try:

- deleting the "u/0" from the URL
- signing out of all of your Google accounts, and back into just one
- trying the /exec in an "incognito" window

Comment: Yes, you were right about the "u/0/", once I removed it, it worked .. seems like there is sort of a bug on suggested URL by google here. Also, note that opening the suggested url (with "u/0/") in incognito tab didn't make it work either (obvious : I had no "indexed connected user" in incognito). Didn't had to sign out from all my accounts, just had to apply your first point and it was OK. Thanks ! :-)

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit strange that Google would corrupt their own URL. It could be worth going through the issue tracker to see if this is logged. I'll admit I didn't work this one out, but I can't find the original post that mentions this.

Comment: Created one this morning https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72798634

Comment: My issue is similar to this.  The /exec link from the script editor doesn't contain /u/0 but when I try to use the exec url on the Chrome browser with multiple accounts logged in, it adds /u/1 to the link and therefore breaks it.  Is there anyway known way to prevent this?

Comment: Thanks for the incognito trick - something changed recently with the web-app URL stuff, and only incognito seems to be working for me at the moment